# (404)Not Found Error - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, wsdl, axis

I try to access a web service server with its wsdl address. I mean, I am the client. I used intellij idea to generate the codes. But whenever I try to run my code I get this error. Can this be my fault or do I just need to warn server side?

Comment: Did you check your url?

Comment: yes, wsdl address is correct.